# Is there no type conversion in bit operation in the php

Tags: php

```
'4'&'64'=='4'
```

[image]

Is there no type conversion in bit operation in the php?

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php: _“If both operands for the &, | and ^ operators are strings, then the operation will be performed on the ASCII values of the characters that make up the strings and the result will be a string. In all other cases, both operands will be converted to integers and the result will be an integer.”_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on argument types.
[PHP bitwise operators documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php) says:

> **If both** operands for the &, | and ^ operators **are strings**, then the operation will be **performed on the ASCII values** of the characters that make up the strings and the **result will be a string**.

> In all other cases, both operands will be converted to integers and the result will be an integer.

So the expected behavior is:

```
var_dump(  '4' & '64'  );
// Output: string(1) "4"

var_dump(   4  &  64   );
// Output: int(0)

var_dump(  '4' &  64   );
// Output: int(0)

var_dump(   4  & '64'  );
// Output: int(0)
```